# How to Generate 404 error forcefully in Yii

Tags: error-handling, yii

I am using Yii framework and i want to generate `404` error if no recode found in database.
Is there any smart way so that `Yii default error handler` should be invoked.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
throw new CHttpException(404,'The specified post cannot be found.');
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.error

Comment: @imre-l Is it possible to return an Http Error without throwing an exception? Because I'm using MailLogRoute and now even simple 403 errors are mailed to me. It's an intentional error, so not a failure of a programmer so I think it shouldn't be an Exception. Is there a 'cleaner' way? > just return a http response with 403 without using CHttpException?

Comment: Have you tried using "200" as code? It's the "OK", so I think the server should let it pass.